# Creating a version of a monospaced font where bold is the same as regular

Tags: fonts, bold

I am using the [Fixedsys Excelsior](https://www.download-free-fonts.com/details/91888/fixedsys-excelsior) font as a custom font in several programs, and every now and then, the interface requests the text to be bold. I am assuming that in this case, a bold version of the font is somehow generated automatically by "thickening" the letters, and I don't like it. The following is an example from the Python interpreter in Ghidra:

[image: Too bold text]

I am wondering if it is possible to add a bold variant of this font which is in fact the same font, i.e. whenever a program displays Fixedsys Excelsior as bold, it will display Fixedsys Excelsior regular.

My naive impression was that this could potentially be achieved using [fonttools](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools) and the corresponding `ttx` data type/format, but naturally this may be the entirely wrong tool. One way or the other, I have no idea how to achieve my goal and would be very grateful for any ideas how to do it. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a font to be regarded as the bold variant of another, it must have the following metadata properties:

- It has to have the same *family name.*
- The *OS/2 weight class* must be *700 Bold.*

It may help to keep some other metadata *(weight name,* etc.) sane, in particular avoiding overlaps.

There are several programs that can modify these, but the one I am familiar with is FontForge. With this, your procedure is:

1. Open the *Fixedsys Excelsior* font file with FontForge.
2. *Element → Font Info.*
3. Change *Fontname, Name for Humans,* and *Weight* to something else. Don’t touch *Familiy Name.*
4. Go to the *OS/2* section.
5. Choose *700 Bold* for the *Weight Class.*
6. *OK.*
7. Accept to create a new ID.
8. *File → Generate Fonts*
9. Save under a different file name.
10. Ignore all potential warnings.
11. Install both fonts.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works perfectly in every application ... _except_ for the Ghidra Python prompt. Alas, I am considering this a bug in Ghidra, or possibly Java.